# OpenNETCF.Net.Networkinformation Examples - Querying WiFi Information

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, opennetcf

I've started playing with the OpenNETCF Framework to capture information related to the WiFi connection available on the device I am writing an application for. I found a very usefull example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446491.aspx but found that:

a. I could not get the MAC address for the AP I was currently connected to through this methodology.
b. This referenced an older version of the framework making use of deprecated classes and methods.

I found references on the OpenNETCF website that the .Net.Networkinformation namespace was the current route to take to get to what I was looking for. Unfortunatly some quality time with Google was unable to find any meaningfull examples or documentation for this namespace.

So I come here.

What I am looking to expose is the following for my application.

1. Currently active network adaptor.
2. If current adaptor is wireless and connected.
3. Information (e.g. MAC Address and Name) of Access Point currently connected to.